# ConverterParameter -- Any way to pass in some delimited list?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, ivalueconverter

Basically, if I have:

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyValue, Converter={StaticResource TransformedTextConverter},
           ConverterParameter=?}" />
```

How would you go about passing in some type of array of items as the ConverterParameter. I figured I could pass in some type of delimited list, but I'm not sure what type of delimiter to use, or if there is a built-in way to pass in an array of parameters?

Comment: are you trying to use the parameter as an index into MyValue? why not just parse it up in your Convert method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `ConverterParameter` is of type `object` that means when the XAML is parsed there will not be any implicit conversion, if you pass in any delimited list it will just be interpreted as a string. You could of course split that in the convert method itself.

But as you probably want more complex objects you can do two things when dealing with static values: Create the object array as resource and reference it or create the array in place using element syntax, e.g.

1:

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <x:Array x:Key="params" Type="{x:Type ns:YourTypeHere}">
        <ns:YourTypeHere />
        <ns:YourTypeHere />
    </x:Array>
</Window.Resources>

... ConverterParameter={StaticResource params}
```

2:

```xml
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <Binding Path="MyValue" Converter="{StaticResource TransformedTextConverter}">
            <Binding.ConverterParameter>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type ns:YourTypeHere}">
                    <ns:YourTypeHere />
                    <ns:YourTypeHere />
                </x:Array>
            </Binding.ConverterParameter>
        </Binding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 4):

`ConverterParameter` is not a dependency property, so cannot be based on a binding

You could hardcode a value, such as an x-delimited list of parameters which you `.Split(x)` in your Converter, or you can use a `MultiConverter` which allows you to send multiple bound values to a Converter.

```xml
<!-- Not sure the exact syntax, but I'm fairly sure you have 
     to escape the commas -->
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyValue, 
           Converter={StaticResource TransformedTextConverter},
           ConverterParameter={};@,@|}" />
```

Or

```xml
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyMultiConverter}">
            <Binding Path="MyValue" />
            <Binding Path="Parameters" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
<TextBlock>
```